# Passing session value to another page in PHP

Tags: php

I have a drop down list on page1.php

```
<?php $dbtables = $_COOKIE["notables"];`
 if ($dbtables == "41")
 echo "option selected = 'true' value = '41'>41</option?>";
 else echo "<option value='41'>41</option>"; ?>

if(isset($_POST['Submitbtn'])){$_SESSION["tables"] = $_POST['notables'];
die("<script>location.href = 'page2.php'</script>");
```

i want to display the value to page2.php using session but it is blank.
    No.of tables:

i have started session_start(); on both page. is there anything wrong?

Comment: did you check `session_start()`'s return value? Did you check if `session_id()` returns the same value on both pages?

Comment: are those ticks `\`` part of your code?

Comment: Hi marc B , how do i do it?

Comment: blank page may mean syntax errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: no this ' are not part of the code

Comment: plus you're repeating `if ($dbtables == "41")`

Comment: hi it still show empty string

Comment: hi fred, sorry i copy double time. i post here for page1.php coding. <?php $dbtables = $_COOKIE["notables"];
 if ($dbtables == "41")
 echo "option selected = 'true' value = '41'>41</option?>";
 else echo "<option value='41'>41</option>"; ?>

Comment: please edit your code as per what you are really using. check for errors as stated in my previous comment and remember that cookies only take effect once the page has been reloaded and not on initial page load, and should be checking to see if the cookie has indeed been set.

Comment: hi fred i have edited.

Comment: i have the error Undefined variable: in C:\xampp\htdocs\...........

Comment: What does `print $_POST['notables'];` give you in the submit condition in "page1.php"?

Comment: it will post the value (notables) from the dropdown list. actually notables = no.of tables in short